# Safari-style tabs with Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, tabs

Does anyone know of a widget that gives Safari-style tabs that expand and contract between certain dimensions when the window is resized, spilling over to a drop down menu when **(amount of tabs)*(min tab width) > (window width)**?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with changing the css properties like this

http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/rUtKa/

Comment: Thanks! That does nothing of the sort, though. It does not contain any logic for flowing over into a sink, nor is it really a tab implementation. But thank you for the tip nonetheless.

Comment: I didn't get you isn't this what you want to be . .